# Check if string appears as its own word - Python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Let's say that I am looking for the word `"or"`. What I want is to check whether that word appears as a word or as a substring of another word.

E.g.

> Input - "or"
>   Output - "true"
>
> Input - "for"
>   Output - "false"

I suppose I could check if the chars before and after are letters but is there a more efficient/easier way of doing it? Thanks

**Edit**
In addition, the string will be part of a sentence. So I want "I can go shopping or not" to return true but "I can go shopping for shoes" to return false. 
Therefore using == wouldn't work. I'm sorry I should've mentioned this earlier

Comment: If it's just one word why don't you just use `==`?

Comment: It is because it is part of a sentence not just one word. For example I want "I can go shopping or not" to return true but "I can go shopping for shoes" to return false. So using == wouldn't work. I'm sorry I should've mentioned this in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'\bor\b', 'or')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f445333a5e0>
>>> re.search(r'\bor\b', 'for')
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```
import re

def contains_word(text, word):
    return bool(re.search(r'\b' + re.escape(word) + r'\b', text))

print(contains_word('or', 'or')) # True
print(contains_word('for', 'or')) # False
print(contains_word('to be or not to be', 'or')) # True
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a checker with just a test if it is **in** the line

```
def check_word_in_line(word, line):
    return " {} ".format(word) in line

print(check_word_in_line("or", "I can go shopping or not")) //True
print(check_word_in_line("or", "I can go shopping for shoes")) //False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nltk (Natural Language Toolkit) to split the sentence into words, and then check if some word exists with `==`.

[NLTK Installation](http://www.nltk.org/install.html)

[NLTK Package Download](http://www.nltk.org/data.html)

```
import nltk

def checkword(sentence):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    return any((True for word in words if word == "or"))

print(checkword("Should be false for."))
print(checkword("Should be true or."))
```

Comment: I've edited your answer for two reasons: 1. there is no need to write `else` after an `if` followed by a `return`, because you can only return from a function once; 2. there is no need in the `if/else` clause when you want to return a boolean based on a condition, because the condition itself is a boolean.